# jquery click only loads first image regardless of image clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to display an image in a div based on the thumbnail that is clicked. I have two sizes, small and large, and want to display the large version in the div. I have tried a couple of code amendments based on other answers, but I am no further forward (these are commented out in my code) .

I have produced a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLrbyjdq/) to show the problem.

Can anyone help me find the solution?

HTML & JS:

```
    <div class="banner_slide clearfix">
    <ul>
    <li class="link"><img class="img-swap thumb-img" src="https://www.ryokuyou.co.jp/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/m01_hyoushi_small.jpg" /><div class="tridown"></div></li>
    <li class="link"><img class="img-swap thumb-img" src="https://www.ryokuyou.co.jp/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/m01_honbun_small.jpg" /><div class="tridown"></div></li>
    <li class="link"><img class="img-swap thumb-img" src="https://www.ryokuyou.co.jp/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/m01_tojikata_small.jpg" /><div class="tridown"></div></li>
    <li class="link"><img class="img-swap thumb-img" src="https://www.ryokuyou.co.jp/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/m01_sabisu_small.jpg" /><div class="tridown"></div></li>
    </ul>
    <img id="banner-img" src="https://www.ryokuyou.co.jp/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/m01_sabisu_large.jpg" />
    </div>
```

```
    $(".img-swap").click(function () {
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#banner-img").fadeOut(function () {
    //$(this).attr("src", source); 
    $(this).attr("src", $(".img-swap").attr("src").replace("small", "large"));
    //$("#banner-img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("small", "large"));
    $(this).fadeIn();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because once you trigger this line:

```
$(this).attr("src", $(".img-swap").attr("src").replace("small", "large"));
```

The .img-swap class is not unique on the dom, so it picks the frist dom element that matches the class. To fix this, a possible solution is to save in a varible the element that you click on:

```
$(".img-swap").click(function () {
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#banner-img").fadeOut(function () {
      $(this).attr("src", source.replace("small", "large"));
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  });
```

Comment: `varsource` needs to be `var source`

Comment: I just tried this in the JSfiddle and it solved my problem. I can see where I was going wrong now so thank you for explaining.